# Los enlaces de descarga no me funcionan en tablet ni smartphone

Tags: html5, css3

Los enlaces como:

```
<a target= '_blank' class="enlacedescarga" href="
https://mega.nz/#!qNNUwQTa!w4c-1GZ_9XUNtdy_fqN-UGAFNi6LTgsGh8vliNORnvs
">Se busca banda</a>
```

Me funcionan en pc pero no en tablet.

**¿Qué cambio tengo que hacerle al `html` o `css` para que funcionen?**

Comment: Lo he probado en iphone 6s chrome y safari... funciona perfecto... en css lo dudo que tengas el problema, mientras que no hayas asignado al link: `pointer-events: none;`... Tu elemento parece estar bien... (aunque no me gusta que uses comillas simple)... haz intentado sin el atributo `target="_blank"`?

Comment: En que SO, android, IOS, otro? A mi en android me pide que instale la app de Mega para poder abrir los archivos, yo diría que no es problema de tu código sino de Mega

Comment: en mi tablet samsung tab 4 no me van. en el móvil android si funcionan

Answer (score 0):

Esto está mal:

```html
<a
 target= '_blank'
 class="enlacedescarga"
 href="https://mega.nz/#!qNNUwQTa!w4c-1GZ_9XUNtdy_fqN-UGAFNi6LTgsGh8vliNORnvs"
>Se busca banda</a>
```

Debería estar escrito así:

```html
<a
 href="https://mega.nz/#!qNNUwQTa!w4c-1GZ_9XUNtdy_fqN-UGAFNi6LTgsGh8vliNORnvs"
 target="_blank"
 class="enlacedescarga"
>Se busca banda</a>
```

Comment: Y porque esta mal?

Comment: Los valores de los atributos pueden ir entre comillas simples o dobles, el orden tampoco afecta al funcionamiento de los enlaces. Explica por qué está mal

Comment: El error está en el espacio que dejaste entre el primer atributo target = '...'. Lo conveniente es trabajar bajo estándares de la W3 y las recomendaciones para SEO de Google y Moz: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html y https://moz.com/learn/seo/internal-link

Comment: Los navegadores resuelven ese espacio sin problemas. Tampoco veo en los enlaces que pones que diga nada sobre eso

Comment: O sea que... viste los ejemplos que citan los enlaces que he pasado, escribir al antojo total los navegadores luego lo solucionan, ¿no?

Comment: Yo no he dicho eso, digo que no pone que dejar un espacio entre el atributo y el valor sea incorrecto, los validadores de html lo dan por bueno y en ninguna documentación veo que no se pueda hacer. Y además quitar el espacio tampoco resuelve el problema planteado

Comment: No lo sé si lo resolvió o no con mi aporte.